# MYSQL max() and group by error:only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, min

I have question about a MySQL query that is logging error's since updating the MySQL-5.7.
The error is the "only_full_group_by" which is will spoken off on stackoverflow.

In many answers it's stated not to disable this option but improve your sql query.

The query that I'm using is returning the minimum and maximum values of a counter per hour.

```
SELECT MAX( counter ) AS max, 
       MIN( counter ) AS min, 
       DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%H:%i') AS dt 
FROM table1 
WHERE date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY YEAR(date_time), MONTH(date_time), DAY(date_time), HOUR(date_time)
```

as I understand from the error message I'm missing one of the items from the SELECT cause in the GROUP BY cause. But however I restort/remove/add items I'm not getting the result I got before the upgrade to MySQL-5.7.

I tried to subquery the main query to improve the SQL query. But somehow I can't recreate the results.

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%H:%i')` will be indeterministic, as you are grouping upto `hour` level only; so it can return any minute in that hour, hence the error.

Comment: I tried removing the 'minute' part (%i), but then I completely lose the real order of the data set. The results show the hours in order from 00 up to 23, but the result should be order by the real date_time and start from now (say 20:00) like: 20, 21, 22, 23, 00 .... 19, 20

Comment: Can you please set up a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL isn't able to determine the functional dependence ...  between the expressions in the GROUP BY clause, and the expressions in the SELECT list.

The non-aggregate expression in the SELECT list (**`DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%H:%i')`** includes a minutes component.  The GROUP BY clause is going to collapse the rows into groups by just hour.  So the value of the **minutes** is indeterminate... we know it's going to come from some row in the group, but there's no guarantee which one.

(The question reference to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` seems to indicate that we've got some understanding of indeterminate values...)

The easiest (fewest) changes fix would be to wrap that expression in a `MIN` or `MAX` function.

```
 SELECT MAX(t.counter)                          AS `max`
      , MIN(t.counter)                          AS `min`
      , MIN(DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%H:%i'))   AS `dt`
   FROM table1 t
  WHERE t.date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  GROUP
     BY YEAR(t.date_time)
      , MONTH(t.date_time)
      , DAY(t.date_time)
      , HOUR(t.date_time)
  ORDER
     BY YEAR(t.date_time)
      , MONTH(t.date_time)
      , DAY(t.date_time)
      , HOUR(t.date_time)
```

If we want rows returned in a particular order, we should include an `ORDER BY` clause, and not rely on MySQL-specific extension or behavior of `GROUP BY` (which may disappear in future releases.)

---

It's a bit odd to be doing a `GROUP BY` year, month, day and not including those values in the SELECT list. (It's not invalid to do that, just kind of strange. The conditions in the `WHERE` clause are guaranteeing that we don't have more than 24 hours span for `date_time`.

My preference would to do the `GROUP BY` on the same expression as the non-aggregate in the SELECT list. If I ever needed more than 24 hours, I'd include the date component:

```
 SELECT MAX(t.counter)                             AS `max`
      , MIN(t.counter)                             AS `min`
      , DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + INTERVAL 0 DAY AS `dt`
   FROM table1 t
  WHERE t.date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  GROUP
     BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
  ORDER
     BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

--or--

if we always know it's just one day's worth of `date_time`, and we only want to return the hour, then we can group by just the hour. The same expression as in the SELECT list.

```
 SELECT MAX(t.counter)                             AS `max`
      , MIN(t.counter)                             AS `min`
      , DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%H:00')           AS `dt`
   FROM table1 t
  WHERE t.date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  GROUP
     BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%H:00')
      , DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H')
  ORDER
     BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Comment: thank you spencer7593 for your clear explanation. This really solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX( counter ) AS max, 
       MIN( counter ) AS min,
       YEAR(date_time) AS g_year,
       MONTH(date_time)AS g_month,
       DAY(date_time) AS g_day,
       HOUR(date_time) AS g_hour 
FROM table1 
WHERE date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY g_year, g_month, g_day, g_hour
```

Or you can get rid of redundant data if you always do it for 1 day:

```
SELECT MAX( counter ) AS max, 
       MIN( counter ) AS min,
       DAY(date_time) AS g_day,
       HOUR(date_time) AS g_hour 
FROM table1 
WHERE date_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY g_day, g_hour
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for your awnser. Your query returned the same result is "spencer7593" code did. I upvoted his awnser as he did explain the underlaying structure. This might also be usefull for other users.